# Choose whether variable is a user or system environment variable in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I only have headless access to a windows machine, and I need to specifically set a variable as a user environment variable (cannot be system). I would also like to set it permanently, and not just for the cmd session. Is there a way of doing this just through the command prompt?

Comment: Yes, with command __setx__. Open a command prompt window and run `setx /?` for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding **@Mofi's** comment :

Using `setx` you can set a variable as persistent (like `system variable`)
but it will only be avaiable on the next run of a CMD Interpreter.

So if you need to use it in the actual handle of the CMD too,
you'll better set it twice :

example :

```
@echo off
set "MyVar=test1234"
setx MyVar test1234
```

Like this it will be avaiable **NOW** and for the **NEXT** CMD sessions